# While building docker images getting below error

Tags: docker, image

WARNING: buildx: failed to get git commit: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:

'git  [...] -- [...]'

tried to build image but getting above error
because there is no relationship with git why I'm getting git related issues becuase I am creating docker image from Dockerfile

Comment: What command are you running? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I ran `docker build .` inside a new Git repository without any commits.

Committing the first commit should remove the error message.